# su daemon command stuck in batch file

Tags: batch-file, adb, daemon

I'm rooting AVD by batch script. in my case batch script stuck on daemon command. how do I run "adb -e shell su --daemon&" from a batch file? the command acts like an editor in the command prompt and the last two commands are not executed. pls help.

Here is my batch root_script.bat

```
adb remount
adb -e push D:\armv7\su /system/bin/su
adb -e shell "su root exit"
adb -e shell chmod 06755 /system/bin/su
adb -e shell su --install
adb -e shell su --daemon&
adb -e shell setenforce 0
adb -e shell am start eu.chainfire.supersu/.MainActivity
```

Comment: The ampersand has special meaning in a batch file. So you need to escape it with a `^`.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.
if you mean ^ is used before & operator i used that but batch file prints as string on console.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `&` operator from [tag:bash]??

Comment: @aschipfl no I'm using batch script not bash.